# Add the same elements of an array in a recursive way

Tags: php

Hello my goal is to add the same values ​​in an array and remove the repeated values ​​then add the sum of these repeated values ​​in the same array in a repetitive way until all the elements of the array will be distinct.
I made this code but it does it just once, how to repeat this action several times until the good result? thanks

```
function magic($arr)
{

    $result = array_filter(array_count_values($arr), function ($el) {
        return $el > 1;
    });
    foreach ($result as $k => $val) {
        $a[] = $k;
        $b[] = $k * $val;
    }

    $c[] = array_merge(array_diff($arr, $a), $b);

    return $c;
}


print_r(magic([5, 5, 8, 8, 10, 9,20, 7, 7]));//found:[10,9,20,10,16,14]  excpected:[9,40,14,16]( stape to find  result:[10,9,20,10,16,14]==>[20,9,20,16,14]==>[9,40,14,16])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an associative array ad add the same key

```
foreach ($result as $k => $val) {
    $a[$k] = (isset($a[$k]) ? a[$k] + $val : $val ;
}
```

Comment: i don't think so